# Deploying a FIPS enabled Apache/OpenSSL

Tags: windows, openssl, fips

I've built Apache with mod_ssl/OpenSSL for FIPS compliance (I'm building and installing in a Windows environment) and it works locally. I can do the following:

```
openssl md5 C:\path\to\random\file.txt  # this will succeed and spit out hash info

set OPENSSL_FIPS=1

openssl md5 C:\path\to\random\file.txt # this will fail and spit out an error about MD5 being disabled in FIPS mode

openssl sha1 C:\path\to\random\file.txt # this will succeed and spit out hash info
```

But when I copy my Apache build (the entire bin directory and modules directory) to an existing internal SSL testbed that we have attempt to run the same commands, any use of openssl to perform a hash (md5 or sha1) will give me the following error:

```
1444:error:2D06B06F:FIPS routines:FIPS_check_incore_fingerprint:fingerprint does not match:.\fips\fips.c:232:
```

What is causing it to break when I copy it to another machine? Thoughts?

Comment: What version of OpenSSL?  Also, are you sure it's not using some other libcrypto.dll (or whatever the .dll is on Windows), like maybe something in a system directory?